# Weird errors in console app

Tags: macos

Yesterday I noticed this log in console:

> networkd[183]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:]
>   client com.apple.WebKi.1353 setting source application without
>   entitlement

especially when I using Safari. 
What is that mean and how can I fix it?